# Merge two arrays by keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
$array_1 = array(
            array('name' => 'Jon', 'user' => 'Apple'),
            array('name' => 'Dave', 'user' => 'Windows')     
                );

$array_2 = array(
            array('name' => 'Jon', 'user' => ''), 
            array('name' => 'Jonson', 'user' => ''), 
            array('name' => 'Dave', 'user' => '')
        );
```

I need to get this:

```
$array_result = array(
            array('name' => 'Jon', 'user' => 'Apple'), 
            array('name' => 'Jonson', 'user' => ''), 
            array('name' => 'Dave', 'user' => 'Windows')
        );
```

I have tried `array_merge()` and have tried to filter arrays `array_filter()` but Can't find solution. I'll be very thankful for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your arrays associative with array_columns third argument then use array_replace_recursive to get the change you want.
The optionally use array_values to get an indexed array again.

```
$array_1 = array_column($array_1, Null, "name");
$array_2 = array_column($array_2, Null, "name");


$result = array_values(array_replace_recursive($array_2, $array_1));

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Jon"
    ["user"]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Jonson"
    ["user"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Dave"
    ["user"]=>
    string(7) "Windows"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/EcgFh